# Speed-optimizing tree data parser

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, optimization

I'm working on an assignment where the input is in the following format, and I have to parse it as fast as possible:

```
5 (
 5 (
  3 (
  )
 )
 3 (
  3 (
  )
  3 (
  )
 )
 5 (
  2 (
  )
  4 (
  )
 )
)
```

It is a tree structure of "Employees", the numbers are for the subsequent task (index of language).

Each employee can have any number of subordinates and one superior (the root node is "Boss").

Here's my parser: (Originally I used `Scanner` and it was short and simple, but about twice slower)

```
// Invocation
// Employee boss = collectEmployee(null, 0, reader);

private Employee collectEmployee(final Employee parent, int indent, final Reader r) throws IOException
{
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean nums = false;
    while (true) {
        char c = (char) r.read();
        if (c == 10 || c == 13) continue; // newline
        if (c == ' ') {
            if (nums) break;
        } else {
            nums = true;
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    final int lang = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
    final Employee self = new Employee(lang, parent);

    r.skip(1); // opening paren
    int spaces = 0;
    while (true) {
        r.mark(1);
        int i = r.read();
        char c = (char) i;
        if (c == 10 || c == 13) continue; // newline
        if (c == ' ') {
            spaces++;
        } else {
            if (spaces == indent) {
                break; // End of this employee
            } else {
                spaces = 0; // new line.
                r.reset();
                self.add(collectEmployee(self, indent + 1, r));
            }
        }
    }
    return self; // the root employee for this subtree
}
```

I need to shave a few more cycles off the code, so it will pass the strict requirements. I've profiled it and this part is indeed what slows the app down. The input file can have up to 30 MiB so any little improvement makes big difference.

Any ideas appreciated. thanks.

(Just for completeness, the Scanner implementation is here - it can give you idea of how I parse it)

```
private Employee collectEmployee(final Employee parent, final Scanner sc)
{
    final int lang = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    sc.nextLine(); // trash the opening parenthesis

    final Employee self = new Employee(lang, parent);

    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        Employee sub = collectEmployee(self, sc);
        self.add(sub);
    }

    sc.nextLine(); // trash the closing parenthesis

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are doing a lot of data pushing with the `StringBuilder` — it may be beneficial to keep an int value that you update on encountering a decimal char (`'0'`-`'9'`) (`num = num * 10 + (c - '0')`) and storing/resetting on encountering a non-decimal. That way you can also get rid of Integer.parseInt.
2. You seem to be using/checking indentation for the hierarchy, but your input format contains braces which makes it an S-Expression based syntax — so your parser does a lot more work than needed (you can ignore spaces and handle braces using a stack of Employees).
3. I'd consider using a [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark and run with perf-asm (if available) to see where your code spends its time. Really, it's an invaluable tool.

Comment: I've tried exactly that (1), and it was a lot slower :(
I'm not really sure why, but StringBuilder and parseInt is faster in this case.

Comment: Sounds fishy, because while Integer.parseInt does some tricks to speed up parsing consecutive numbers, the numbers you have are so small as to make this a non-issue. Alas, because I don't have your alternative code, I cannot hope to untangle this conundrum.

Comment: After a lot of fiddling and combining the approaches, I got it working, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, the basics are reading and parsing, and what you do with the data.

Reading and parsing, by recursive-descent, should be totally IO-bound.
It should run in a fraction of the time it takes to read the characters.

What you do with the data depends on how you design the data structure.
If you're not careful, you can spend way more time than you want in memory management.

Anyway, here's a bone-simple parser in C++. You can convert it to any language you like.

```
void scanWhite(const char* &pc){while(WHITE(*pc)) pc++;}

bool seeChar(const char* &pc, char c){
  scanWhite(pc);
  if (*pc != c) return False;
  pc++;
  return True;
}

bool seeNum((const char* &pc, int &n){
  scanWhite(pc);
  if (!DIGIT(*pc)) return False;
  n = 0; while(DIGIT(*pc)) n = n * 10 + (*pc++ - '0');
  return True;
}

// this sucks up strings of the form: either nothing or number ( ... )
bool readNumFollowedByList(const char* &pc){
  int n = 0;
  if (!seeNum(pc, n)) return False;
  // what you do with this number and what follows is up to you
  // if you hit the error, print a message and throw to the top level
  if (!seeChar(pc, LP)){ /* ERROR - NUMBER NOT FOLLOWED BY LEFT PAREN */ }
  // read any number of number ( ... )
  while(readNumFollowedByList(*pc)); // <<-- note the recursion
  if (!seeChar(pc, RP)){ /* ERROR - MISSING RIGHT PAREN */ }
  return True; 
}
```

Comment: This looks badass, I'll have to learn C++ soon :D
Unfortunately doing this in Java will be pain, and also I'm parsing a stream instead of large string. Could work for shorter trees though

Comment: @MightyPork: Have a "global" `char c`, and a routine `AcceptChar()` that does `c<<cin`. (If it hits the end, have it set `c=0;`.) Then, call that guy once before you start, to load `c` with the first character. Then, replace `*pc` with `c`, and replace `pc++` with `AcceptChar()`. If you do this, Java should be able to go just as fast as C++ (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

A proper implementation should really use a state machine and a `Builder`. Not sure how more/less efficient this is but it certainly lends itself to later enhancements and some real simplicity.

```
static class Employee {

    final int language;
    final Employee parent;
    final List<Employee> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee(int language, Employee parent) {
        this.language = language;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append(language);
        if (!children.isEmpty()) {
            for (Employee child : children) {
                s.append("(").append(child.toString()).append(")");
            }
        } else {
            s.append("()");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    static class Builder {

        // Make a boss to wrap the data.
        Employee current = new Employee(0, null);
        // The number that is growing into the `language` field.
        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
        // Bracket counter - not sure if this is necessary.
        int brackets = 0;
        // Current state.
        State state = State.Idle;

        enum State {

            Idle {

                        @Override
                        State next(Builder builder, char ch) {
                            // Any digits kick me into Number state.
                            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                                return Number.next(builder, ch);
                            }
                            // Watch for brackets.
                            if ("()".indexOf(ch) != -1) {
                                return Bracket.next(builder, ch);
                            }
                            // No change - stay as I am.
                            return this;
                        }
                    },
            Number {

                        @Override
                        State next(Builder builder, char ch) {
                            // Any non-digits treated like an idle.
                            if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                                // Store it.
                                builder.number.append(ch);
                            } else {
                                // Now we have his number - make the new employee.
                                builder.current = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(builder.number.toString()), builder.current);
                                // Clear the number for next time around.
                                builder.number.setLength(0);
                                // Remember - could be an '('.
                                return Idle.next(builder, ch);
                            }
                            // No change - stay as I am.
                            return this;
                        }
                    },
            Bracket {

                        @Override
                        State next(Builder builder, char ch) {
                            // Open or close.
                            if (ch == '(') {
                                builder.brackets += 1;
                            } else {
                                builder.brackets -= 1;
                                // Keep that child.
                                Employee child = builder.current;
                                // Up to parent.
                                builder.current = builder.current.parent;
                                // Add the child.
                                builder.current.children.add(child);
                            }
                            // Always back to Idle after a bracket.
                            return Idle;
                        }
                    };

            abstract State next(Builder builder, char ch);
        }

        Builder data(String data) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                state = state.next(this, data.charAt(i));
            }
            return this;
        }

        Employee build() {
            // Current should hold the boss.
            return current;
        }
    }
}

static String testData = "5 (\n"
        + " 5 (\n"
        + "  3 (\n"
        + "  )\n"
        + " )\n"
        + " 3 (\n"
        + "  3 (\n"
        + "  )\n"
        + "  3 (\n"
        + "  )\n"
        + " )\n"
        + " 5 (\n"
        + "  2 (\n"
        + "  )\n"
        + "  4 (\n"
        + "  )\n"
        + " )\n"
        + ")";

public void test() throws IOException {
    Employee e = new Employee.Builder().data(testData).build();
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    File[] ins = Files.listFiles(new File("C:\\Temp\\datapub"),
            new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.getName().endsWith(".in");
                }

            });
    for (File f : ins) {
        Employee.Builder builder = new Employee.Builder();
        String[] lines = Files.readLines(f);
        ProcessTimer timer = new ProcessTimer();
        for (String line : lines) {
            builder.data(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Read file " + f + " took " + timer);
    }
}
```

prints

> 0(5(5(3()))(3(3())(3()))(5(2())(4())))

Note the `0` first element is the `boss` you mentioned.

Comment: I have some serious doubts this will be efficient, sounds like overkill. Also, the input stream has up to 30 MB.

Comment: @MightyPork - I'd be interested in some real comparison metrics. You'd be surprised how effective a state machine can be at finding the most efficient mechanism.

Comment: Okay here's a dataset that's used for testing - implementation of Employee is trivial, so you can try profiling the different approaches -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64454818/TMP/datapub.tar.gz

Comment: @MightyPork - A millisecond timer takes an unmeasurable time for most of those. The slowest one (pub08 at 29mb) took 1.120 seconds to parse. Environment: Intel Core i7 860 @ 2.80GHz. You really need to compare yours with mine on the same machine.

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with the original code?

Comment: @MightyPork - No! `self.add` is missing, and so is the outer definition of `Employee`. Surely if you are asking for some speed optimisation you are prepared to compare the posts yourself? I've added my testing code.

Comment: Oh well I have already got it working, this is merely because you wanted to see the benchmarks. Your code doesn't use Reader so I'd have to implement some kind of line splitting mechanism and that'd also add overhead, so I can't directly compare it.